# ajax REST API security prevent client side hijacking

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was building a topup system where user can pay something and some credits will goes into their e-wallet. But then later on I found if the logged in user is smart enough, he can trigger the ajax and dump any value.

How do I prevent that? since any user can open the dev tool and do a post request.

Comment: I think you are talking about [Self-XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-XSS)

Comment: Question is far too broad. We have no idea what you have set up

Comment: @charlietfl like why do u need to set a key in ur POST's header?

Comment: @MariaJane If i understood your problem, you have to make a "proxy" that will get the post request and after checking against the successful payment or request counter or whatever you want then the post request to the e-wallet will send server-to-server call. Make sense?

Comment: @4EACH is that how the ecommerce system do it?

Comment: @MariaJane, Most of eCommerce systems work like this, this is best practice, The proxy have important job here. Proxy takes care of client request, Proxy does the business logic, Proxy takes care of 3rd party requests and response, Proxy helps to debug this process by logging etc ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to setup SSL first, don't pas parameter in your URL, and use CSP if possible. The OWAP site specializes in this have has many helpful guidelines on how to achieve what you need.

[CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP)

[OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page)

### UPDATE

I appears that this needs more explanation. Hat you are describing is an XSS attack and most likely falls under the category of either a man-in-the-browser or a CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery). You can help to prevent it by first insuring that your site is using SSL. SSL makes use of the https protocol. That protocol allows the server and application to setup an agreed upon security encryption after an initial handshake. All transactions that occur afterwards happen on that established security layer; the SSL. The top browsers are pushing for this to be mandatory for web apps but especially if you are doing financial transactions over the web.

[SSL certificates explained](https://youtu.be/SJJmoDZ3il8) 
[Google Will Soon Shame All Websites That Are Unsecured](http://motherboard.vice.com/read/google-will-soon-shame-all-websites-that-are-unencrypted-chrome-https)
[Man-in-the-browser attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-browser_attack)

CSP allow you to specify particular domains and origins.
[Introducing Content Security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/Introducing_Content_Security_Policy)

Also you can use CORS to set acceptable http headers.

Here's an example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.bobank.com
[
  { id: 456346436, ... }
]
```

[Your API-Centric Web App Is Probably Not Safe Against XSS and CSRF](http://www.redotheweb.com/2015/11/09/api-security.html)

CSP in .NET
[Content Security Policy (CSP) for ASP.NET MVC](http://rehansaeed.com/content-security-policy-for-asp-net-mvc/)

CORS in .NET
[Enabling Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Comment: I don't know what technology you are using on your server.  I use asp.net Web API and when a client (mobile app, web app, etc.) log in he receives a token for some period of time. So in this time you muat use this token to access the server.  Here it's a link with a full example: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

Comment: With a main-in-the-middle or main-in-the-browser attack someone can grab that token and use no matter how short lived it is, if it is there they can grab it.

Comment: I know...that's why I use https too.